# TargetInvocationException thrown selected item changed

Tags: c#, wpf, devexpress

I'm trying to regenerate the content (`ItemSource`) of a Devexpress `TreeList` when the selection of another `TreeList` is changed. However, I get the following exception when it runs:

> System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException

**Code**

```
    void treeListControl1_SelectedItemChanged(object sender, SelectedItemChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        string st = ww.nList.CurrentCellValue.ToString();
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(st);

        ww.treeList.ItemsSource = null;

        ww.treeList.ItemsSource = drawOrderBook(currCycle, st);
        // drawOrderBook is some complex method that generates the data to displayed based on the filter st and the static data currCycle

    }
```

Comment: delete all that and use proper databinding.

Comment: Is ItemsSource set in Xaml too?

Comment: Check the InnerException property of the TargetInvokationException instance. This property returns an actual exception being thrown. The actual exception will tell you what went wrong.